# PHP creates corrupt thumnbail

Tags: php

This is the thumnbail script I'm working on and it ends up creating a corrupt 33 byte image. I think the problem is in the exif_imagetype if statement but I'm not sure. I would appreciate any help.

```
    // Original image
    $filename = 'images/T' . $neutralName;

    // Get dimensions of the original image
    list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    // The x and y coordinates on the original image where we
    // will begin cropping the image
    $left = 10;
    $top = 5;

    // This will be the final size of the image (e.g. how many pixels
    // left and down we will be going)
    $crop_width = 140;
    $crop_height = 100;

    // Resample the image
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
    if ((exif_imagetype($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $current_width, $current_height);
        imagejpeg($canvas, $filename, 100);
    } else if ((exif_imagetype($_FILES["photo"]['tmp_name'])) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $current_image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $current_width, $current_height);
        imagegif($canvas, $filename, 100);
    } else {
        $current_image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $current_width, $current_height);
        imagepng($canvas, $filename, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Is there more code? What are you doing with $canvas after that statement?

Comment: What inside that image? Maybe it's 33 symbols of error message?

Comment: All the code is right there, canvas is defined right above the if statements. And yeah, I believe there are 33 symbols of error. It keeps thinking that any picture is a PNG so that means it's failing the first and second test even though it might be a JPG.

Comment: I also think it's an error. You can display it by doing a readfile, and without putting image headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you're trying to open an image that doesn't exist or isn't an image... In each of your each, you're finding the file type via `$_FILES["photo"]['tmp_name']` but directly below that if the condition is true, you're using `imagecreatefromXXX($filename)`. Shouldn't you be opening the image file that was uploaded and not the path to which you're saving the image? Opening the path `$filename` (assuming it exists) would always copy the same exact square and save it. Doesn't seem like a viable thing you'd be doing.

Comment: You're totally right, I fixed it now. Instead of checking the very original picture and seeing if it's JPG or PNG or something else, I'm going to test $filename to see what type of picture it is. I already tested it and it works. Thanks a ton! It's just something that I was blind to.